# How to recover Nexus 5 data from memory chip

Tags: nexus-5, fastboot, bootloader

Edit 2:
My Nexus 5 doesn't boot up the OS or the Recovery, but it boots the Bootloader. The service people speculate that the power IC isn't able to supply enough power for the first two but it's enough for the bootloader. I have flashed a new 5.0 image using fastboot, and all fastboot operations report success. So I'm pretty convinced the internal memory is fine.

How do I recover my data? I don't know any fastboot method to do it.

Is there a way to connect the motherboard to an external power source so that adb works and I can read the data?

Is there a way to remove the memory chip and read it using a card reader or something?

Comment: in normal cases an OTA update does only update the system partition and does not update the bootloader. Of course I have no insights what google is doing with their bootloader for the nexus devices but IMHO it is normally not needed to update the bootloader for a step from 4.4.4 to 5.0 as also the old bootloader should still work as the hardware which needs to be initialized prior calling the kernel will ofc remaijn the same after an update. Although it can be needed if there is a signature check for the called kernel or something.

Comment: Umm, did you make any head way? Did you get the device to power down? Are all the keys unresponsive or just the volume buttons?  As far as the flash-all.bat script did it complete? There was a lil bit of tunnel vision on the bootloader what about the rest of the system?  Minus the exposed it's doubtful  it's hard brinked the majority of the time that requires hardware damage.

Comment: So, I went on a crazy wild adventure dealing with all this, and sorry to say, it hasn't led me anywhere fruitful yet. Current status is, phone is being moody. Seriously. Most of the time, it stays in a Qualcomm emergency download mode: 'Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008' with Windows having a proper driver installed. There is an awesome guide over at XDA which shows how to restore boot images using this mode. My tries fail at 'Serial port open FAILED' every time. But, after fiddling with the buttons for a long time (sometimes 10-15 min) the bootloader loads up. And miraculously, it works now.

Comment: Since last time, it had failed at the reboot-bootloader step, I skipped the flash-all script, and manually flashed the system image. I ignored the radio because it was already the correct version. Everything happened perfectly, like before... until the reboot. Something is wrong with the boot process. The partitions seem to be hale and hearty (I can access bootloader, flash files properly). The most evident appearance of a problem is that the screen blacks out after the appearance of the Google logo, whether booting up the OS or into recovery (stock or custom, it doesn't matter).

Comment: @BoLawson Thanks for asking, I've updated the question.

Comment: @Andy356 could you link the XDA guide?